# ASP ajax work on local host but not work with public ip

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis

I wrote custom ajax call and call to asp web services. Its simple asp web form project.

Its working o local host. but after setup it on IIS with public IP its not working. My IIS version 7.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.. just add

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

in web.config